# What can you use Pythagoras Theorem for in real life?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, education

I know I can use Pythagoras Theorem to calculate the sides of a right triangle.

But so, how and what for the formula can be used in real life? I need some practical examples.

Comment: To calculate the hypothenuse of a right triangle knowing the catheti, to calculate the diagonal of a rectangle...

Comment: Construct a right angle on a building site with just a measuring tape (please don't do this in real life :-)).

Comment: To calculate the hypothenuse of the right triangle you make when you move $19.37\text{m}$ east and $7.05\text{m}$ north... All sorts of stuff.

Comment: What do you define as "real life" and why is calculating the sides of a right triangle *not* a "practical example" for you?  Anyone in construction or engineering does this regularly.

Comment: " Anyone in construction or engineering does this regularly."  And anyone whose job is to write op-ed pages will never need to do it ever.  I always hate "what about real life" questions because to live there isn't anything anyone *has* to do and to live there will be things *one* will have to do that will not be universal....

Comment: More trig but if you are in a sailboat that can't sail into the wind so that to get from point A to B you must sail upon a course as close to $AB$ as possible but you can only go 45 degrees to the wind for some distance  to $C$ and then tack at a 90 degree angle and sail to $B$.  The distance $AB$ is $\sqrt{AC^2 + BC^2}$ and to calculate the time to allow and distance to do this you must consider the actual course of tacking.

Comment: Getting a sofa through a narrow doorway!

Comment: Yes, but we all benefit from the things not universally done and should be thankful to those who took the trouble to do it. Ships and airplanes use a grid system (station (x), butt line (y) and waterline (z) to locate the structure of the vessel on a blueprint. The distance formula derived from the Pythagorean Theorem is often used to determine the lengths of tubing and wiring runs.If the geometry is loaded into a CAD system, an algorithm will utilize PT for the same function.

Comment: To reword my irritation of "what are real life application" question is that the statement says "we can do X" so the the question "what's the real life application" is answered by "well, uh... whenever you need to do X, you can".  Whenever you need to know the sides of a right triangle is the real life application; what more does anyone need?  Okay you can use rectangles and right triangles to break down and find distances in all circumstances and ... surely that's as "real life" for anyone. How much more specific do you need?  Guiding airplanes, height of buildings, best routes in traffic...

Comment: Without the hatery, those should be answers, they have lots of examples. Knowing the distance is basic, but how can you guide an airplane with it though? Sure you can know the altitude, but...?

Answer (score 1):

Is a cut corner square?  One way to find out with only a ruler is to mark off the point three units away on one side and four units away on the perpendicular side.  Then measure between the marks.  A square corner = five units.

Answer (score 0):

Pythagoras's Theorem is used to compute distances in Euclidean space parametrised with Cartesian co-ordinates.

For many purposes, therefore, it secures the validity of the mathematical model which is used to describe and reason about the "real world" (for some purposes this model is insufficiently accurate and ideas of such as Riemann and Einstein provide models in which Pythagoras does not apply as a universal geometric truth).

This implicit use is more significant than any explicit application in some "real world" example.

Once the validity of the model is established we don't go back to first principles most of the time - people just use the model and take its foundations for granted.